# A MAP sensor small piece of plastic and a nipple fell into intake

Tags: renault, clio, plastic, manifold-absolute-pressure-sensor, intake

I tried to remove the MAP sensor (the car is Clio 3 1.6 16v k4m engine) and it was moving very easily and just tried a little bit to pull it out and a small piece of plastic with an oring was just fallen out in the intake...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to retrieve that part out of the intake of your engine.  One way or the other it's going to get into the valves or all the way into the combustion chamber and there is a distinct possibility that it may cause catastrophic damage.

While it may be a bit of work to pull the intake manifold off the engine to get at it, you don't want to risk the damage it can easily cause.